# What would be the best way to make responsive layout with wide width table using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I'm using bootstrap. Everything is pretty much set, but table.
When I'm seeing my website with smartphone, it shows with responsive design but table looks pretty messy.
All the contents stick out from the edge of table.
What would be the best way to handle this kind of thing?
Anyone has any idea???

Update:

[image: Please take look at right edge!]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/

Comment: how does it look like? got any visual examples?

Comment: @Chanckjh I added visual example. Please take a look!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give it a min-width. This happens all the time. If you look in your browser and make it smaller you can see the same problem when you scroll to the right. The background does not the scrollarea unless it has a width.